# Facebook SDK error: Session provided to a request in un-opened state

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have modified Facebook Friend picker example.
I am first time using this facebook sdk.
and here is the logcat.

```
10-15 06:43:16.189: D/Facebook-Example(26914): Exception: com.facebook.FacebookException: Session provided to a Request in un-opened state.
```

I have checked my hashkey, but still this error is coming.

This isnt any duplicate question, because the last solution didnt help out.

This error comes when it comes to that page when friends are being loaded.

Comment: Did you open the session before giving it to a request? The session object needs to be in the "opened" state before it has an access token to use.

Comment: yes,the user is logged in in earlier page. The user is successfully logged in .
@MingLi

Comment: I have the same problem. did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem implementing methods for manager changes of Session.
I mean after the autentication  you have to wait that the session is opened. 
So I added UiLifecycleHelper object and the method that facebook suggests:

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

private MainActivity activity;
private Context context;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(activity, sessionCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}


// Define a private variable that contains the implementation of the Session.StatusCallback listener:
private Session.StatusCallback sessionCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        makeMeRequest(session); // my request
    } else {
                    ...
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, nativeDialogCallback);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    activity = null;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```